# Moving previous documentation sets and ios SDKs into XCode 4.5

Tags: xcode, installation

I have a slow internet connection and am trying to avoid downloading previous XCode documentation sets and SDKs.

I just installed XCode 4.5 and see they included no documentation sets for any iOS version.  There is also only the SDK for iOS 6.

I deploy on iOS version 4.2 and later.  I also had many iOS SDKs for testing and all the docsets.

Is it an issue to copy my 4.2, 4.3, 5.0, etc. docsets and SDKs to the XCode 4.5?

The new install location is different so I'm even wondering where I would move them to.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My old Developer folder was in the root HD folder.  I don't know if that's typical.  The docsets were located here:
HD/Developer/Documentation/DocSets

The simulators were located here:
HD/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs

Unfortunately I wasn't able to get XCode 4.5 to recognize any docset I moved from my XCode 4.2 installation.  I had to let XCode 4.5 download them.

I did successfully move content from my developer XCode 4.5 GM to the AppStore XCode 4.5.

The .docset files are stored here:
~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets

Nothing had to be done as XCode 4.5 from the AppStore recognized what I had downloaded using my XCode 4.5 GM.  This is good news because it means future XCode versions will probably recognize them as well.

The simulator files are stored inside the XCode.app itself:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/

I just copied these folders from the XCode 4.5 GM to the App Store XCode 4.5 into the above folder:

- iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk
- iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk
- iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk

My understanding is that the minimum supported deployment target with Xcode 4.5 or later is iOS 4.3 so I didn't move any other simulator SDKs.

Of course, you need to control-click (or right mouse click) the XCode application and select Show Package Contents before you can navigate to the Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/ folder.

I don't know what this means when a new Xcode is release and the App Store installs the update.  Will it wipe out these SDKs I moved?  I've already made a backup of my modified XCode 4.5 in case they are lost when upgrading XCode through the App Store.

Hope this is helpful.